# Issue with HTML string formatting function algorithm

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I came across this problem somewhere and it's very interesting.

Problem:

> Write a string formatting function that turns the data object into a
> formatted VALID HTML string

Code:

```
const data = {
  str: 'hello world',
  formatting: [
    {
      type: 'i',
      positions: [2, 4],
    },
    {
      type: 'i',
      positions: [5, 9],
    },
    {
      type: 'b',
      positions: [7, 13],
    }
  ]
}

function outputHTMLString(data) {

}
```

**Expected Output:** **(NOTE: It must be a valid HTML)**

```
he<i>ll</i>o<i> w</i><b><i>or</i></b><b>ld</b>
```

The issue I'm having is that, since it has to be a valid HTML, I need to break the `<i/>` at position 7. This is very confusing. What can I try next?

This is my attempt (not very optimal):

```js
const data = {
    s: 'hello world',
    formatting: [{
            type: 'i',
            positions: [2, 4],
        },
        {
            type: 'i',
            positions: [5, 9],
        },
        {
            type: 'b',
            positions: [7, 13],
        }
    ]
}

function outputHTMLString(data) {
    const formMap = data.formatting.reduce((acc, elem, index) => {
        for (let p of elem.positions) {
            const e = [p, elem.type];
            acc.push(e);
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

    formMap.sort((a, b) => {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    });

    // console.log(formMap);

    const len = data.s.length;
    let s = data.s.split('');
    let current;
    const stack = [];
    let last = ''; //i0 = <i>, i1=</i>, b0=<b>, b1=</b>

    for (let [i, arr] of formMap.entries()) {
        //   console.log(i, arr, stack);
        const index = arr[0],
            elem = arr[1],
            topStack = stack[stack.length - 1];
        if (s[index]) {


            if (stack.length) {

                if (topStack === elem) {
                    let current = s[index];
                    s[index] = '';
                    while (stack.length) {
                        s[index] += '</' + stack.pop() + '>';

                    }
                    const next = formMap[i + 1][0];
                    console.log('stack:', stack, index + 1, 'next:', next);
                    if (next > index) {
                        s[index] += '<' + formMap[i + 1][1] + '>';
                    }
                    s[index] += current;
                } else {

                    s[index] = '</' + stack.pop() + '>' + '<' + elem + '>' + '<' + topStack + '>' + (s[index] || '');
                    stack.push(elem, topStack);
                }
            } else {
                s[index] = '<' + elem + '>' + (s[index] || '');
                stack.push(elem);
            }

        } else if (index > len - 1) {
            s[len - 1] = s[len - 1] + '</' + elem + '>';
        }

    }
    console.log(s);

}

console.log(outputHTMLString(data));
```

Comment: @Teemu thank you for the response. How will substring solve this problem? I'm suspecting it's a stack problem. However, I'm not sure how to break even to make it valid HTML. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question. It looks like you should not break `<i>` at 7, instead you need to start `<b>` at 7, and then break it at 9, and the close `<i>` and re-start `<b>`.

Comment: Added @Teemu but I don't feel this is optimal by any means. Wondering if others have a better way of implementing this. Would very much appreciate any insights/code

Comment: You declare `const formMap` but then try to sort it?

Comment: @RickardElimää You could sort an array that's declared with `const` what's wrong with that?

Comment: Never mind. I wasn't paying attention when I tried it. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to solve this.

---

### Using a tree

Define a tree data structure representing the HTML content as it's being built. Each node knows its `start` and `end` indices in the original string. To format within a range of indices, find all nodes in the tree overlapping that range.

The tree is "ternary" since as well as representing the `start` and `end` indices of the formatted content, each node can have `left` and `right` children for the content to the left and right of those indices.

---

### Using stacks

For each formatted range, insert the pairs `(start, '<tag>')` and `(end, '</tag>')` into a list, then sort by the first component of each pair. Iterate through the pairs in order; when you see an open tag, push the tag-name to the stack and write the open tag. When you see a close tag, if its tag name is on top of the stack then pop it and write the closing tag.

Otherwise, pop the other tag names from the stack into a temporary stack while writing closing tags, until you pop the tag name you want to close. Then close that, and re-open all the tags in the temporary stack (in reverse order) while pushing them back to the main stack.

For example, if the current output is `he<i>ll</i>o<i> w<b>or` and the next thing to do is close the `<i>` tag, then we pop `b` from the main stack and push it to a temporary stack, write `</b>` to the output, pop `i` from the main stack and write `</i>` to the output, then pop `b` from the temporary stack and push it back to the main stack, writing `<b>` to the output.

---

Here's a quick implementation of the stack solution:

```js
function formatHTML(text, formats) {
    const boundaries = formats.map(f => ({
        tag: f.type, open: true, position: f.positions[0]
    })).concat(formats.map(f => ({
        tag: f.type, open: false, position: f.positions[1]
    }))).sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position);
    const out = [];
    const stack = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (let boundary of boundaries) {
        out.push(text.substring(i, boundary.position));
        if (boundary.open) {
            stack.push(boundary.tag);
            out.push('<', boundary.tag, '>');
        } else {
            const tmp = [];
            while (true) {
                const t = stack.pop();
                out.push('</', t, '>');
                if(t == boundary.tag) { break; }
                tmp.push(t);
            }
            while (tmp.length) {
                const t = tmp.pop();
                stack.push(t);
                out.push('<', t, '>');
            }
        }
        i = boundary.position;
    }
    out.push(text.substring(i));
    return out.join('');
}
```

This isn't optimal since it when multiple tags should be opened or closed at the same position, it doesn't try to order them in a way which minimises the number of tags needed overall. The output for your test case is:

```html
he<i>ll</i>o<i> w<b>or</b></i><b>ld</b>
```

Comment: Thanks @kaya3 for your response. This is awesome. Could you please share some code for your approach #2 (I have added what I have attempted in my OP) however, nowhere close to optimal solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Very helpful. thanks @kaya3.

For the tree implementation, Sounds like RangeTree / Interval tree could be the right set for this kind of problem set.